# AppActivate Excel-vba: Excel flashes in taskbar and doesn't activate

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, vba, taskbar, focus

In an Excel-vba module:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim Outlook As Object
    Set Outlook = CreateOutlook()
    Set Outlook = Nothing
End Sub
Function CreateOutlook() As Object
    Dim Outlook As Object
    On Error Resume Next
        Set Outlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Outlook Is Nothing Then Shell "Outlook"
    On Error Resume Next
        Do While Outlook Is Nothing
            Set Outlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    AppActivate Application.Caption 'This line doesn't cause an error but excel icon flashes in taskbar and doesn't activate.
    Set CreateOutlook = Outlook
    Set Outlook = Nothing
End Function
```

I have Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit.

Comment: You need to edit your question and indicate what error you received.

Comment: What happens if you try "AppActivate "Microsoft Outlook"" instead?

Comment: @duDE why would he want to activate Access if he works in Excel?

Comment: This line doesn't cause an error but excel icon flashes in taskbar and doesn't activate.

Comment: @LPChip Sorry, I thought OP wants to activate Outlook. His question is not very detailed :)

Comment: I have edited the question for clarification.

Comment: You still have not answered @duDE question.  Edit your question.

Comment: It may work if you try to activate your worksheet. It has been a while, but I think the code is: `ThisWorkbook.activesheet.activate`

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Instead of:

```
AppActivate Application.Caption
```

This:

```
SendKeys "% i"
```

Then:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim Outlook As Object
    Set Outlook = CreateOutlook()
    Set Outlook = Nothing
End Sub
Function CreateOutlook() As Object
    Dim Minimize As Boolean
    Dim Outlook As Object
    Minimize = False
    On Error Resume Next
        Set Outlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Outlook Is Nothing Then
        Shell "Outlook"
        Minimize = True
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
        Do While Outlook Is Nothing
            Set Outlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Minimize Then SendKeys "% i"
    Set Outlook = Nothing
    Set CreateOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End Function
```